How to make a tie bar look correct in PowerPoint?
In Microsoft Word, the digraph t͡s (using the Unicode character Combining Double Inverted Breve in the Combining Diacritical Marks block) is displayed correctly:

In PowerPoint, the same text is formatted incorrectly:

Is there any way to override this behavior, or would a messy screenshot/text box solution be the only way?

I had a play with this. It appears to be related to the font you use in PowerPoint. See below examples with Arial and System-UI fonts.


Using other fonts may present a better outcome.

Interesting. I was using Times New Roman for both the images I posted, and Palatino Linotype for the rest of my project in PowerPoint. I think I'll look for similar fonts that render correctly.
